# Iphone App Icon error 57 x 57 iOs Version < 7.0

Tags: ios, image, validation, icons

I'm trying to validate my app on Organizer/Archive, but I'm getting this error:

> "Missing required icon file. The bundle does not contain an app icon
>   for iPhone / Ipod Touch of exactly  '57x57' pixels, in .png format for
>   IOS versions < 7.0." At File Inspector -> App Icon I'm checking
>   Iphone: iOS 7.0 and Later Sizes and iOS 6.1 and Prior Sizes.

So appears 6 places to fill with some icon image:
1 - iPhone Spotlight - iOS 5,6 Settings - iOS 5-7 29pt
   I used icons: 29x29 and 58x58 (29x29@2x)
2- iPhone SpotLight iOS 7 40pt 
   icon: 80x80 (40x40@2x)
3- iPhone App iOS 5,6 57pt
   icons: 57x57 and 114x114 (57x57@2x)
4 - iPhone app iOS 7 60pt
   icons: 120x120 (60x60@2x)

But even with image 57x57, I still getting the error.
There is something else that I have to do?

Answer (score 9):

The developer guide shows all the icon you could use with image Asset

[image]

Further info here
https://developer.apple.com/LIBRARY/IOS/qa/qa1686/_index.html

Comment: Ok, I'm using Icon-small, icon-small-40, icon, icon-60. But I still getting that error.

Comment: are you using Image Asset or simply images name in plist ?

Comment: I`m using catalogs - General App icons, like the image you uploded in the post

Comment: try one thing. Go to Organizer Archives.. archive->show in finder. Then check package contents. what does the plist show for the icons

Comment: are you asking about contents.json ?

Comment: {
  "images" : [
    {
      "size" : "29x29",
      "idiom" : "iphone",
      "filename" : "Icon-Small.png",
      "scale" : "1x"
    },
    {
      "size" : "29x29",
      "idiom" : "iphone",
      "filename" : "Icon-Small@2x.png",
      "scale" : "2x"
    },
    {
      "size" : "40x40",
      "idiom" : "iphone",
      "filename" : "Icon-Small-40@2x.png",
      "scale" : "2x"
    },

Comment: {
      "size" : "57x57",
      "idiom" : "iphone",
      "filename" : "Icon.png",
      "scale" : "1x"
    },
    {
      "size" : "57x57",
      "idiom" : "iphone",
      "filename" : "Icon@2x.png",
      "scale" : "2x"
    },
    {
      "size" : "60x60",
      "idiom" : "iphone",
      "filename" : "Icon-60@2x.png",
      "scale" : "2x"
    }
  ],
  "info" : {
    "version" : 1,
    "author" : "xcode"
  }
}

Comment: Request for update: the HIG that Apple points me to, do not mention 57x57 app icon. See https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/icons-and-images/app-icon/. At the time, 57pt and 72pt icons (and their 2x scales) are still required. The developer guide link in this answer no longer works. I had to manually add the icons to Contents.json of the asset catalog - the 57pt icons are for "iphone" idiom, the 72pt icons are for "ipad" idiom. Correct idiom is needed to make icons in the catalog assigned.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same question as you. I think you can do as follows:

First, your app may supoort iOS 6.X ,so you must have a 57x57 icon; if your app changed to just support iOS 7, it will be OK

Second, you can do this if you want iOS 6.X for your app:
Do not use Asset Catalog, because it's just for iOS 7.X. Use the iOS 6.X method in App setting - app icons.

Answer (score 0):

For me, it was simply that I had to rename the file from `Icon-57.png` to `Icon.png`.